# After displaying a validation error message page is moving to next page by clicking next button

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura

I'm trying to apply a validation error just before navigating to Next Page of my application. If the user has clicked on next button it will check whether a user have provided a valid "sort code" or not. If user not provided a valid "sort code" field the validation error should visible to user.

After user user has provided the valid sort code then only it allows to move next page.

I have written logic for that but what happening is validation error is showing up for incorrect sort code entered by user but the page is not staying and it automatically moves to next page immediately after displaying validation error message.

Kindly please check the below and how to stop execution of page after validation error comes up.

Controller.Js

```js
    moveNext: function(component, event, helper){
        helper.sortCodeVerify(component, helper);
        helper.prepareRequest(component, helper, false, arrSelectedOrgs, arrDeSelectedOrgs);
    }
},
```

Helper.js

```js
prepareRequest: function(component, helper, isDraft, arrSelectedOrgs, arrDeSelectedOrgs){
    var params = {
        orgId: component.get('v.uiControls.orgId'), 
        orgSelected: JSON.stringify(arrSelectedOrgs),
        orgDeselected: JSON.stringify(arrDeSelectedOrgs),            
        jsonIoCaseUI: JSON.stringify(component.get('v.ioCase')),
        jsonOnboardEntities: JSON.stringify(component.get('v.lstOnboardEntities'))
    }

    helper.callApex(component, isDraft ? 'saveDraft' : 'saveAndMoveNext', params, function(response){
        var status = response.success;
        if(status){
            //The if condition is for Draft button logic
            if(isDraft){
                helper.setToaster(component, 'Saved as draft', 'success');
                component.set('v.uiControls.inProgress', false);
            //else block is for move next button logic.
            }else 
                // Else block is executing after clicking the"movenext" button.
                window.open('/lightning/n/Client_Form?source=lex&c__orgId='+component.get('v.uiControls.orgId'), '_self');   
            }else{
                var error = helper[response] ? helper[response] : response;//helper.UNKNOWN_ERROR;
                helper.setToaster(component, error);
                component.set('v.uiControls.inProgress', false);
            }
        }, function(error){
            component.set('v.uiControls.inProgress', false);
        })
    },
                
    sortCodeVerify : function(component,helper){
        var orgId = helper.getURLParam('orgId');
        //alert(orgId);
        var action = component.get("c.fetchSortCode");
        action.setParams({
            IoCaseOrgid:orgId  
        });
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){
            var state = response.getState();            
            var res = response.getReturnValue();
            //alert(res);
            if(res == true){
                helper.setToaster(component, 'Sort code is blocked.Consider using an alternative sort code that is not blocked if accounts are not part of a CAS/MAS arrangement', 'error');
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action); 
    },
```

Apex Class

```java
@AuraEnabled
public static boolean fetchSortCode(String IoCaseOrgid){
    IO_Case__c lstIoCases = [SELECT Id, Name, io_Sort_Code__c FROM IO_Case__c WHERE io_Organisation_ID__c = :IoCaseOrgid limit 1];

    Boolean res = false;
    list<onboardingSortCode__mdt> sortCodeList = [SELECT Id, Label, sortCode__c FROM onboardingSortCode__mdt];
    if(sortCodeList.size() > 0){
        for(onboardingSortCode__mdt m :sortCodeList){
            if(m.sortCode__c.contains(lstIoCases.io_Sort_Code__c)){
                System.debug('Sort Code ---->' + lstIoCases.io_Sort_Code__c);
                res = true;
            }
        }
    }

    system.debug('res'+res);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is seen since you are calling both helper methods consecutively as below :

```
helper.sortCodeVerify(component, helper);
helper.prepareRequest(component, helper, false, arrSelectedOrgs, arrDeSelectedOrgs);
    }
```

Your requirement is to stop navigation on a particular condition then you need to conditionally call the `helper.prepareRequest` from `helper.sortCodeVerify's` callback as below :

(I'am guessing this after looking at the `helper.prepareRequest` method which contains a `window.open` function call.)

```
sortCodeVerify : function(component,helper){
        var orgId = helper.getURLParam('orgId');
        //alert(orgId);
        var action = component.get("c.fetchSortCode");
        action.setParams({
            IoCaseOrgid:orgId  
        });
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){
            var state = response.getState();            
            var res = response.getReturnValue();
            //alert(res);
            if(res == true){
                helper.setToaster(component, 'Sort code is blocked.Consider using an alternative sort code that is not blocked if accounts are not part of a CAS/MAS arrangement', 'error');
            }
            else {
              //Method returned false . Hence , call the navigation method
              helper.prepareRequest(component, helper, false, arrSelectedOrgs, arrDeSelectedOrgs);
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action); 
    }
```

Controller.Js will just call `helper.sortCodeVerify` as below  :

```
moveNext: function(component, event, helper){
        helper.sortCodeVerify(component, helper);
    }
```

**Edit** : I would recommend to rename `sortCodeVerify` to a more generic name.