# Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

Hope all are doing great!

```
                I have a visualforce page and run in Varacode scan it results one High Flaw in the below page.
                I have tried to fix in many ways by using keywords like JSENCODE, HTMLENCODE and also using JSINHTMLENCODE. But the flaw is not going.

                Can anyone please suggest how fix that flaw.

                Apex Page :
                --------------

                <apex:page standardController="Debt_Pricing_Template__c" extensions="RestViewOnDPT" >
                <script>
                if({!showDptPage}==true){
                    if({!Debt_Pricing_Template__c.Is_New_Template__c}==true){
                        window.location.href='/apex/DPTView?id={!JSINHTMLENCODE(Debt_Pricing_Template__c.id)}';
                    }
                    else{
                        window.location.href= '/apex/DPTView_Old?id={!JSINHTMLENCODE(Debt_Pricing_Template__c.id)}';
                    }
                }
                else{
                    window.location.href='/home/home.jsp';
                }
                </script>
                </apex:page>
                
                
                Apex Code :
                
                public  class RestViewOnDPT {
        public String dptId {public get;public set;}
        public Boolean isSelfSanction {public get; public set;}
        public Boolean showDptPage{public get; public set;}
        public Boolean showDptPageForOwner{public get; public set;}
        public String DptOwnerName{public get; public set;}

        public RestViewOnDPT(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        Boolean isTeamLeader = false;
        showDptPageForOwner = true;
        showDptPage = true;
        Id userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        dptId = controller.getId(); 
        Debt_Pricing_template__c dpt = [Select Is_New_Template__c,Id,Template_Name__c ,CreatedById, Customer_Name__r.Restricted_View__c,Opportunity__r.Mark_as_Private__c,Opportunity__r.OwnerId,Customer_Name__r.OwnerId, Customer_Name__c,Name_TeamLeader__c,Status__c, Owner.name,Opportunity__c From Debt_Pricing_Template__c where Id=:dptId limit 1];

        List<GroupMember> DptGm = [Select UserOrGroupId, GroupId From GroupMember  where GroupId = '00G20000001QuIn'];

        System.debug('DPTGM='+DptGm );
        Boolean isGrpMember= false;
        for(GroupMember  dptGMUser:DptGm )
        {   
            if(userId == dptGMUser.UserOrGroupId){
            isGrpMember = true;
            break;
            }
        }


        if ('Self Sanction'.equalsIgnoreCase(dpt.Template_Name__c)){
            isSelfSanction = true;
        }else{
            isSelfSanction = false;
        }
        List<AccountTeamMember> accTeamMbrList = [select UserId from AccountTeamMember where AccountId =:dpt.Customer_Name__c and IsDeleted = false];
        for(AccountTeamMember accTeamMbr:accTeamMbrList){
            if(userId == accTeamMbr.UserId && userId == dpt.Name_TeamLeader__c){
                isTeamLeader = true;
            }
        }

        List<OpportunityTeamMember> oppTeamMbrList = [select UserId from OpportunityTeamMember where OpportunityId =:dpt.Opportunity__c and IsDeleted = false];
        for(OpportunityTeamMember oppTeamMbr:oppTeamMbrList){
            if(userId == oppTeamMbr.UserId && userId == dpt.Name_TeamLeader__c){
                isTeamLeader = true;
            }
        }
        List<Profile> prof = [Select Id, Name From Profile Where Name = 'System Administrator' or Name = 'Barclays: System Administrator' order by Name];
        Boolean isAdmin = false;

                if(prof != null && prof.size() == 2) {
                if(String.valueOf(prof.get(0).Id).equals(UserInfo.getProfileId()) || String.valueOf(prof.get(1).Id).equals(UserInfo.getProfileId())) {
                    isAdmin = true;
                }
            }
            if(dpt.Customer_Name__r.Restricted_View__c == true && userId!=dpt.ownerId && !isAdmin && userId!= dpt.Customer_Name__r.OwnerId && !isGrpMember && userId!= dpt.Opportunity__r.OwnerId) 
            {
                if([select count() from AccountTeamMember where accountid=:dpt.Customer_Name__c and userid=:userId and isDeleted=False]==0) 
                {
                    showDptPage = false;
                    DptOwnerName = dpt.Owner.Name;
                }
             
            else if(dpt.Opportunity__r.Mark_as_Private__c == true && userId!= dpt.OwnerId && !isAdmin && userId!= dpt.Opportunity__r.OwnerId && !isGrpMember && userId!= dpt.Customer_Name__r.OwnerId)
             {
                if([select count() from OpportunityTeamMember where OpportunityId =: dpt.Opportunity__c and userid=:userId and isDeleted=False]==0) 
                {
                    showDptPage = false;
                    DptOwnerName = dpt.Owner.Name;
                }
                 if([select count() from AccountTeamMember where accountid=:dpt.Customer_Name__c and userid=:userId and isDeleted=False]==0) 
                {
                    showDptPage = false;
                    DptOwnerName = dpt.Owner.Name;
                }
             }
             
            }
            system.debug('dpt.Status__c='+dpt.Status__c);
        system.debug('userId='+userId);
        system.debug('dpt.Name_TeamLeader__c ='+dpt.Name_TeamLeader__c );
        system.debug('isGrpMember='+isGrpMember);
        system.debug('isTeamLeader='+isTeamLeader);
        system.debug('showDptPageForOwner ='+showDptPageForOwner );

                //LOCKING DOWN DPT FOR DPT OWNER, CREATED BY USER EXCEPT TEAM LEADER & OTHER DPT GROUP USER ONCE IT HAS BEEN SUBMITTED - 10JUL12
            if(dpt.Status__c != null && dpt.Status__c != 'Pending – further information required' && dpt.Status__c != '' && userId != dpt.Name_TeamLeader__c && !isGrpMember && !isTeamLeader){
                showDptPageForOwner = false;
                DptOwnerName = dpt.Owner.Name;
         
                }   system.debug('showDptPageForOwner ='+showDptPageForOwner );
         

        }
        }

                Regards,
                Vineeth
```

Comment: What is the flaw you are facing? Can you share the apex code?

Comment: @MukulMahawariya, I have added apex code can you please have a look into it.

Flaw : Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page (Basic XSS) (CWE ID 80)

Comment: What is the error? Have you tried console.log(!JSINHTMLENCODE(Debt_Pricing_Template__c.id)); whether the value is coming or not

Comment: @MukulMahawariya, After passing like thsi JSINHTMLENCODE(Debt_Pricing_Template__c.id)) the page is not loading. may be the value is not coming up.

Comment: How is this different from your2 most recent questions [1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/399977/improper-neutralization-of-script-related-html-tags-in-a-web-page-basic-xss-c), [2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/399758/after-displaying-a-validation-error-message-page-is-moving-to-next-page-by-click)?

Comment: Also, I want to see you putting in actual effort to format your questions correctly. Look through your previous questions where I or someone else has fixed things for you and read through [the help page on formatting](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a getter setter variable to get the Id

```
<apex:page extensions="RestViewOnDPT" standardController="Debt_Pricing_Template__c">
    
    <script>
        console.log('{!JSINHTMLENCODE(dpt.Id)}');
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Apex -

```
public  class RestViewOnDPT {
    public String dptId {public get;public set;}
    public Debt_Pricing_template__c dpt{public get; public set;}
    public RestViewOnDPT(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
      dpt = [Select Id,Is_New_Template__c,Id,Template_Name__c ,CreatedById, Customer_Name__r.Restricted_View__c,Opportunity__r.Mark_as_Private__c,Opportunity__r.OwnerId,Customer_Name__r.OwnerId, Customer_Name__c,Name_TeamLeader__c,Status__c, Owner.name,Opportunity__c From Debt_Pricing_Template__c where Id=:dptId limit 1];
    }
}
```